# How to organize routing in fastify?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, middleware, fastify

Forgive me for these heretical speeches, but I consider express to be the best library for api building from the developer experience point of view. But what stops me from using it everywhere is that everyone keeps saying (and confirming with benchmarks) that it is slow.

I try to choose an alternative for myself, but I canэt find what suits me.

For example with express I can simply organize the following structure:
userAuthMiddleware.js

```
export const userAuthMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('user auth');
    next();
};
```

adminAuthMiddleware.js

```
export const adminAuthMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('admin auth');
    next();
};
```

setUserRoutes.js

```
export const setUserRoutes = (router) => {
    router.get('/news', (req, res) => res.send(['news1', 'news2']));
    router.get('/news/:id', (req, res) => res.send(`news${req.params.id}`));
};
```

setAdminRoutes.js

```
export const setAdminRoutes = (router) => {
    router.post('/news', (req, res) => res.send('created'));
    router.put('/news/:id', (req, res) => res.send('uodated'));
};
```

userApi.js

```
imports...

const userApi = express.Router();

userApi.use(userAuthMiddleware);
// add handlers for '/movies', '/currency-rates', '/whatever'
setUserRoutes(userApi);

export default userApi;
```

server.js

```
imports...

const app = express();

app.use(bodyparser); // an example of middleware which will handle all requests at all. too lazy to come up with a custom

app.use('/user', userApi);
app.use('/admin', adminApi);

app.listen(3333, () => {
    console.info(`Express server listening...`);
});
```

Now it is very easy for me to add handlers to different "zones", and these handlers will pass through the necessary middlewares. (For example users and admin authorization goes on fundamentally different logic). But this middlewares I add in one place and don't think about it anymore, it just works.

And here I am trying to organize a similar flexible routing structure on `fastify`. So far I haven't succeeded. Either the documentation is stingy, or I'm not attentive enough.

Fastify middlewares that added via 'use' gets req and res objects from the http library and not from the fastify library. Accordingly, it is not very convenient to use them - to pull something out of the body it will be a whole story.

Please give an example of routing in fastify a little more detailed than in the official documentation. For example similar to my example with user and admin on express.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I organize my routes like this:

```
fastify.register(
  function(api, opts, done) {
    api.addHook('preHandler', async (req, res) => {
      //do something on api routes
      if (res.sent) return //stop on error (like user authentication)
    }) 

    api.get('/hi', async () => {
      return { hello: 'world' }
    })

    // only for authenticated users with role.
    api.register(async role => {
       role.addHook('preHandler', async (req, res) => {
         // check role for all role routes
         if (res.sent) return //stop on error
       }) 

       role.get('/my_profile', async () => {
         return { hello: 'world' }
       })

    })

    done()
  },
  {
    prefix: '/api'
  }
)
```

Now all request to api/* will be handled by fastify.

Comment: @muturgan and ofc you can register routes from separated files like this: api.register(require('./routes/users')). Read more here: https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Routes/